# How to search value into a database after concatenate two attributes in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, laravel-7

I have a table Organizations which have the following attributes

```
id
name
acronym
```

And reformat the organization name by concatenate the name and acronym attributes in the Organization Model using Accessor

```
    public function getOrganizationNameAttribute()
    {
        if($this->acronym != null)
        {
            return $this->name. ' ('.$this->acronym.') ';
        }
        else{
            return $this->name;
        }
    }
```

The created form where user have to select organization on typing using datalist

```
<label class="col-form-label">Organization <span class="star">{{$star ?? ''}}</span></label>
<input list="organizations" type="text" name="organization" class="form-control @error('organization_id') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{old('organization',$old ?? '')}}" placeholder="Ex. TGNP Mtandao, Vodacom" {{$req ?? ''}}/>
<datalist id="organizations">
    @foreach($organizations as $organization)
        <option value="{{$organization->organization_name}}"/>
    @endforeach
</datalist>
```

When a user select a particular organization the system will search for the organization_name and get its unique ID if not exists the system will create new value and return the ID

Example have a value in organization table

```
id:1 
name:United Republic of Tanzania
acronym: URT
```

Then form return Organization name as

```
United Republic of Tanzania (URT)
```

Here is My problem:

when a user select **United Republic of Tanzania (URT)** and submit the form i would expect the system to return **ID 1** but instead return null. How do i solve this?

Comment: Where are you compare your search??

Comment: with the name attribute like
```Organization::where('name','LIKE','%'.$value.'%')->get();```

where value is an organization name

Comment: Do you check your `$value` value first?? Is it empty or else?

Comment: yes i check this is the function 
```public function search($value)
    {
        if(!is_null($value)){
            $data= Organization::where('name','LIKE','%'.$value.'%')->get();
            dd($data);
        }
    }```

Comment: May be your form method is `post`? You should use `$request->value`

Comment: this is the model function
```static function search($value)
    {
        if(!is_null($value)){
            $data= self::where('name','LIKE','%'.$value.'%')->get();
            dd($data);
        }
    }```

i call it from controller
```Organization::search($request->value);```

when i die dump ```$valeu``` in the model function display the submitted value which is ***United Republic of Tanzania (URT)*** but when i search it return null but if i search ***United Republic of Tanzania*** without (URT) return ***ID 1***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your html you should use

first add these links to your head

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

then use this select

```
<select name="organizations" id="myorgselect" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
    @foreach($organizations as $organization)
         <option value="{{$organization->organization_id}}">
              {{$organization->organization_name}}
         </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

and add this to your javascrict

```
$("#myorgselect").select2({
tags: true
})
```

see link below for use tagging

https://select2.org/tagging

Comment: this will only select existing data but also, i want a user to create more options which are not exists into a database thus why i'm using ***datalist*** if exists it search for id and fetch if not it'll create new object and fetch id

Comment: select 2 has a option called tagging exacli what you looking for i update my answer

Comment: thank you for this option but i have another question how can you check if the value don't exist and the system create new. Because i tried if the value exists the form submit organization ID if not the form submits new name and my aim is to capture organization ID and store it to another table

Comment: found a solution. 
But thank you again very much i was struggling for this for a long time now i'm okay